# Async function returns value, shows up on console, but undefined elsewhere

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, async-await

Async function returns the value which can be logged on console, but undefined elsewhere

Function call:

```
getData(msg.queryCountry, new Date(), 3, function callback(data){
            console.log('call back func:', data); //works
            
            console.log(data[0].name); // works
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sender.id,{'cdata':data}); //doesn't work; 'undefined' received on receiver's end
        })
        .then( response =>{
                //console.log('response:', response);
                console.log('retrieval successful...');
        })
        .catch( err => {
                console.error(err);
        });
```

Function Definition:

```
async function getData(country, date, level, callback){
   
 let response = await fetch(url);
 let rawdata = await response.text();

 if(response.status == 200 && response.ok == true){
   
  console.log('Response: 200 OK');

   //extracts the data for the country from .csv file received
   let countryUpdate = extractDailyUpdate(rawdata, country);

   callback(countryUpdate);
   
  }

else {
  if(level >= 0){
   //Try again with previous date
    getData(country, prevDate(date, 1), level - 1, callback);
  }
  else {console.log('Ran out of attempts...'); }
    }   
}
```

Output:

`console.log('call back function:', data);` shows the received data, but when I send the data, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sender.id,{'cdata':data});` , on the receiver's end it just shows up as 'undefined'.

I understand that I am mixing up async functions, treating it as synchronous; struggled for 4 days before posting it here.

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to my function definition and it worked

```
 async function getData(country, date, level, callback){


 let response = await fetch(url);
 let rawdata = await response.text();

 if(response.status == 200){

  console.log('Response: 200 OK');

   //Removed this line and to be handled separately 
   //let countryUpdate = extractDailyUpdate(rawdata, country);

   callback(rawdata);

  }

else {
  if(level >= 0){
   //Try again with previous date
    getData(country, prevDate(date, 1), level - 1, callback);
  }
  else {console.log('Ran out of attempts...'); }
    }   
}
```